# WebUserControl Button Click

Tags: asp.net, button, click, webusercontrol

I have a webusercontrol ( MiniUrunControl.ascx ) and in this webusercontrol I add a button and button click function is imgButtonMini_Click.

```
protected void imgButtonMini_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable _tablo = (DataTable)Session["KULLANICISEPETI"];
    foreach (DataRow _row in _tablo.Rows)
    {
        if (_row["urunid"].ToString() == lbUrunID.Text)
        {
            _tablo.Rows.Remove(_row);
            Session["KULLANICISEPETI"] = _tablo;
            break;
        }
    }

    this.Page.GetType().InvokeMember("ShowSepetBilgisi",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, this.Page, new object[] { });

}
```

Now, I add a panel control in Default.aspx and Default.aspx CodeBehind like this;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(ispostback==false) ShowSepetBilgisi();
}

public void ShowSepetBilgisi()
{ 
    DataTable _tablo = (DataTable)Session["KULLANICISEPETI"];

    if (_tablo == null) return;

    pnlMiniUrunler.Controls.Clear();

    foreach (DataRow _row in _tablo.Rows)
    {
        MiniUrunControl _mini = (MiniUrunControl)LoadControl("MiniUrunControl.ascx");
        _mini.SetInfo(_row["urunid"].ToString(), _row["adet"].ToString());
        pnlMiniUrunler.Controls.Add(_mini);
    }
}
```

Ok When run web site , I see all my products ( 10 webusercontrols in panel ) which are added in panel Control. But When I click imgButtonMini button , All control gone and panel is empty. Also my Button Click function doesnot works.

Can you help me what is the problem and How can I run button function ? 
Thanks

Comment: You need to make sure you are adding your web user control in every time if you are dynamically adding it.

Comment: Hi , Will I do this all time ? All time I will add to panel again isnt it ?

Comment: Yeah if you are dynamically creating the user control and adding to the page then you need to do it again. So if you are using LoadControl("...ascx"); you will need to do this on your postback otherwise the control will not be there for events to be wired up to. Are you doing this?

Comment: Re-reading your code (I didnt' have time before) it looks like you aren't as you are only doing it on the first load.

Answer (score 1):

iterate each control in main control for example you have product.ascx control and 
in your product_page.aspx you have a div having `id="pcdiv"` and `runat="server"`. now in C# iterate this way:

```
foreach(control item in (product)div.controls.oftype(product)){
  if(item.value == 'true') {
    Response.write("Got it"); break;//incase only 1 object to iterate
  }
}
```

please check control casting as I haven't test this code but I used this 1 in some project.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code you are only adding the child controls once to the page. They need to be added every time you postback as well if you want to use this approach otherwise the controls will disappear.